# Physics bug in Phaser.JS

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my Phaser.JS file, the physics collider is way too early for the ground (the collision is about 100 pixels from the loaded sprite). This is my code:

```
var gameState = {};
var gx = 0;
function preload() {
    this.load.image('grass', 'grass.png');
    this.load.image('sky', 'sky.jpg');
    this.load.image('mario', 'mario.jpg');
}
function create() {
    var sky = this.add.image(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, 'sky');
     gameState.mario = this.physics.add.sprite(100,100, 'mario');
    sky.setScale(3.3);
    gameState.mario.setScale(.3);
    const platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    platforms.create(0,600, 'grass');
    gameState.mario.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    this.physics.add.collider(gameState.mario, platforms);
}
function update() {
    
}
var config = {
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: 0x00FF00,
    scene: {
        preload, 
        create,
        update
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: {y: 100},
            debug: false
        }
    }
};
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

I have no idea how to fix the collision problem. I am a beginner so I don't know that much about Phaser. Thanks in advance for any answers or comments.

Answer (score 0):

By default, phaser sizes the hitbox for collisions to the size of the texture. If you change that line from debug: false to debug: true, it will draw lines around these hitboxes. Its likely either the ground or character has a hitbox that is larger than the image ‘looks’. Instead of manually changing the size of the hitbox, for a beginner, it will be much easier to crop the image more closely to the edges you expect for collisions. For the textures where the debug lines are larger than expected, you’ll want to crop those textures.